# How to export a subset of a 'less' output

Tags: logs, less

Every so often I need to take a subset of a log file and save it into a file for later use.
I use `less` a lot to view and search within the logs and for exporting the interesting part, I currently do the following:

1. in `less` show the line numbers and note down the line range I need
2. back on the cli, using `sed` I extract the range I need and save this into a file

Is it possible to do this from within `less`, i.e. without the `sed` part?

Answer (score 4):

**Note**, the following command may or may not be valid, depending on your particular installation.

From `man less`.

> ```
>    | <m> shell-command
>           <m> represents any mark letter.  Pipes a section of the input file to the
>           given shell command.  The section of the file to be piped is between the
>           first line on the current screen and the position marked by the letter.
>           <m> may also be ^ or $ to indicate beginning or end of file respectively.
>           If <m> is . or newline, the current screen is piped.
> ```

So when opened a file in `less`, navigate to the desired position and type the following:

```
|. cat >filename
```

`|.` causes `less` to pipe the current screen to the given command. The command is `cat >filename`. `cat` reads from `STDIN` and redirects to `filename`.

You can also open the part within an editor if you want:

```
|. vi -
```

The `-`causes `vi` to read from `STDIN`. Then in `vi` edit whatever you want to edit and save the file with `:w filename`. You can also use another editor, that can read from `STDIN`.